# Content type is missing in the site gallery after adding it from the Content Type Hub using Server Object Model

Tags: site, content

I used the following code to add a content type directly from the ContentType Hub. After running the script, Content Type is added to the Document Library but missing in the Site Gallery.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite siteCTH = new SPSite(ContentHubUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb webCTH = siteCTH.OpenWeb())
        {
            eCTDocument = webCTH.ContentTypes["MyContentType"];

        }
    }
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(CurrentWebUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {               
           SPList docLib = web.Lists[new Guid(libraryGuid)];
           docLib.ContentTypes.Add(eCTDocument);
        }
    }
});
```

So I am not able to re-use the Content Type which I have added to the document Library.

Why the above code is not adding the Content Type in the Site Gallery?